# How to make JavaFX 2.0 ChoiceBox to select its first element

Tags: java, javafx-2

When I create a JavaFX 2.0 ChoiceBox instance like this:

```
final ChoiceBox<String> fontChBox = 
  new ChoiceBox<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList("First", "Second", "Third"));
```

a choice box is displayed with no selection. I would like to select the first element by default. How to do it in JavaFX 2.0?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Give a try to this statement:

```
 fontChBox.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
```

Comment: Actually there is no such a method setSelectedIndex in SingleSelectionModel but there is a selectFirst method which comes to help.

Comment: Please, modify your post so I can select it as accepted answer, thanks!

Comment: It has but it is protected. http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/control/SingleSelectionModel.html

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
fontChBox.getSelectionModel().select(0);
```

if you need to select an element other than the first, pass the index of the element instead of zero.

Answer (score 2):

Try following solution

```
//use this to display first option.
mychoicebox.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();


//to display specific option
mychoicebox.getSelectionModel().selectFirst(index position);
```